# How can I get two auto-increments in one database table?

Tags: sql

I want the post_delete column to generate unique id's so that when I want to delete a comment for e.g. I can refer to the post_delete's value.

**Here is my users TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE users (  
user_id     INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
user_name   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
user_pass   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_email  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
user_date   DATETIME NOT NULL,  
user_level  INT(8) NOT NULL,  
pic_location  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
post_delete  INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
UNIQUE INDEX user_name_unique (user_name),  
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)  
);
```

**and here is my posts TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE posts (  
post_id         INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
post_content        TEXT NOT NULL,  
post_date       DATETIME NOT NULL,  
post_topic      INT(8) NOT NULL,
post_by     INT(8) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (post_id)  
);
```

**and here is my delete query in php**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_by =" . $_SESSION['post_delete'];
```

It says when I include the table that there can only be one auto-increment. How can I change this so that the post_delete can generate unique id's?

Thanks!

Comment: Might I ask why you need a separate unique identifier for that purpose? You could just as well identify the rows to delete by specifying their user_id field.

Comment: Could you explain why `user_id` is not enough? Also tell which database you use. Please edit the question with the answers.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you want such a field? Is it supposed to be some kind of counter? Or why aren't you using the user_id? auto_increment fields aren't a good choice for counters and one unique identifier per table should be plenty ...

Comment: Yes but if I use user_id field it deletes EVERYTHING that same user posted so I want to have like a posted_id that I can refer to when I want to delete a post.

Comment: @Jens Schauder: I'm sorry but what is RDBMS?

Comment: can I do something like this?

Comment: @Joemeister - so you want that post_delete to refer to one specific post? What about the other posts by that user? You need to have a post_id in a 'Posts' table (with a parent reference pointing to the user)

Comment: post_delete  INT(8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

Comment: Ok I updated the whole thing so that you can understand better what I mean...

Comment: If you want to delete one specific post you would use `DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = x`

Comment: @Martin Smith: thats exactly what I want to do but I want to use post_delete in my users table because the user is in a $_SESSION. Can one maybe let it generate random id's for such a column?

Comment: @Joemeister - What you want to do doesn't seem to make sense. You will only be able to have one `post_delete` per user in the users table so it won't help you identify specific posts by a user any better than `user_id` would.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean but how do I then prevent for the user to delete everything???

Comment: Because at this stage when i say $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_by =" . $_SESSION['user_id'];

Comment: it deletes EVERYTHING that user posted... :/

Comment: and $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id =" . $_SESSION['user_id']; does not work for some strange reason...

Comment: You need to pass in the specific `PostId` to delete. Passing in the userid is never going to be specific enough.

Comment: RDBMS = Relational Database Management System -> Oracle, SQL Server, MySql are examples.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use triggers to automatically fill your second auto-incrementing column? I'm not good with triggers, but it sounds like something they could do.

Comment: I'm no expert at triggers as well! How would that change my table as it is now?

Comment: Well, having read the comments on the question - I agree with the guys there, you'll need to get the post id into the page, and retrieve that value in the SQL. How are you triggering the post delete?